# Enabling SSL connections in IIS

Tags: iis, ssl, amazon-ec2

i have an already running web service in an iis server (ec2 amazon), but now i want to make this ws to run also trough https protocol.

I've created an ssl certificate, and i also have bind the site with the https protocol (port 443) and that certificate.

When i go to `https://localhost` in that machine, everything works fine. But the problem is when i try to get trough the ip that i was using in http protocol, with https. The browser just give me an unreachable error.

I've look in the server firewall configuration, and i've found a directive allowing income connections from 443 port, so i discard a firewall problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This question should probably asked at ec2 amazon support forum...

Comment: Do you get an answer from the Server or is it not reachable?

Comment: No. It does not responde at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the EC2 configuration. What i did was:

Go to EC2 dashboard (in AWS) > Security Groups > Click on my server security group > Inbound.
[image: security groups]

There, i saw the https protocol wasn't enable, so i add it:

Edit > Add Rule > HTTPS > Anywhere > Save

[image: https]

Thats all!!